# data type not checked when copy method is used in assignment

Tags: objective-c, pointers, properties, protocols, nscopying

I have a doubt regarding copy

**Overview:**

- I have 2 classes namely `Car` and `MutableCar`
- Both these classes conform to the protocol `NSCopying`
- The method `copy` would return an instance of `Car`

**Question**

1. Why doesn't the compiler doesn't throw any compilation error for the following statement?

   `MutableCar* c2 = [c1 copy];`

   The compiler allows me to assign Car* to a MutableCar* pointer variable
2. Is there any way that this can be prevented from going unnoticed at compile time?

   IMHO this could lead to crashes at runtime as shown in the example below.

**Code** (in separate files)

**Points to note** - Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is used

**Car.h**

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property (readonly) int n1;
@end
```

**Car.m**

```
#import"Car.h"
#import"MutableCar.h"

@interface Car()                //extension
@property (readwrite) int n1;
@end

@implementation Car

@synthesize n1 = _n1;

- (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) pZone
{
    Car* newInstance = [[Car alloc] init];
    newInstance -> _n1 = _n1;
    return(newInstance);
}
@end
```

**MutableCar.h**

```
#import"Car.h"

@interface MutableCar : Car 
@property int n1;            // redeclaration
@property int n2;

@end
```

**MutableCar.m**

```
#import"MutableCar.h"

@implementation MutableCar
@dynamic n1;
@synthesize n2 = _n2;
@end
```

**test.m**

```
#import"MutableCar.h"

int main()
{
    MutableCar* c1 = [[MutableCar alloc] init];
    MutableCar* c2 = [c1 copy];                     //Car* is being assigned to MutableCar* variable
                                                    //Why doesn't the compiler doesn't throw any compilation error ?


    //c2.n2 = 20;                                     //At runtime this throws an error, because c2 is not a MutableCar instance 

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSObject copy]` is declared to return `id`, a type is assignable to any object pointer.  That's why you don't get an error or a warning.

If you override `copy` in `@interface Car`, declaring it to return `Car *`, you'll get a compiler warning on your bogus assignment.

Comment: thanks for the reply Rob, but I tried overriding the `NSCopying` protocol earlier and yet it didn't throw an error at compile time. Just to double confirm below mentioned is my redeclaration in the interface of Car: `- (Car*) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) pZone;`

Comment: You're not sending the `copyWithZone:` message in your main function.  You're sending `copy`.  The compiler doesn't care about what's in some library somewhere.  It cares about what's in the source code you feed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great! you are correct NSObject's copy returns id which needs to be overridden.